# R colSums By Group

Tags: r, plyr

In the following matrix dataset:

```
       1  2   3   4   5  
1950   7 20  21  15  61  
1951   2 10   6  26  57  
1952  12 27  43  37  34  
1953  14 16  40  47  94  
1954   2 17  62 113 101  
1955   3  4  43  99 148  
1956   2 47  31  85  79  
1957  17  5  38 216 228  
1958  11 20  15  76  68  
1959  16 20  43  30 226  
1960   9 28  28  70 201  
1961   1 31 124  74 137  
1962  12 25  37  41 200
```

I have been trying to calculate colSums by decade i.e., find sum the each column from 1950-1959 and then from 1960-69 and so on.

I tried tapply, ddply, etc but couldn't figure out something that would actually work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First we set up the matrix used as input.

```
Lines <- "1  2   3   4   5  
1950   7 20  21  15  61  
1951   2 10   6  26  57  
1952  12 27  43  37  34  
1953  14 16  40  47  94  
1954   2 17  62 113 101  
1955   3  4  43  99 148  
1956   2 47  31  85  79  
1957  17  5  38 216 228  
1958  11 20  15  76  68  
1959  16 20  43  30 226  
1960   9 28  28  70 201  
1961   1 31 124  74 137  
1962  12 25  37  41 200  "
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, check.names = FALSE)
m <- as.matrix(DF)
```

Now, below, we show some alternative solutions.  (1) seems the most flexible in that we can easily replace `sum` with other functions to get different effects but (2) is the shortest for this particular problem.  Also note that there are some slight differences.  (1) produces a data.frame while the other two produce a matrix.

**1) `aggregate`**

```
decade <- 10 * as.numeric(rownames(m)) %/% 10
m.ag <- aggregate(m, data.frame(decade), sum)
```

which gives this data.frame:

```
> m.ag
  decade  1   2   3   4    5
1   1950 86 186 342 744 1096
2   1960 22  84 189 185  538
```

**2) `rowsum`**  This one is shorter.  It produces a matrix result.

```
rowsum(m, decade)
```

**3) `split/sapply`**.  This one produces a matrix as well.  if we had `DF` we could replace as.data.frame(m) with `DF` shortening it slightly.

```
t(sapply(split(as.data.frame(m), decade), colSums))
```

EDIT: added solutions (2) and (3)  Added some clarifications.

Comment: +1 for `rowsum()`. Thanks for expanding your answer to include those additional options.

Answer (score 6):

You first need to define a grouping variable, then you can use your tool of choice (`aggregate`, `ddply`, whatever).

```
> aggregate(x, by=list(trunc(as.numeric(rownames(x))/10)), sum)
  Group.1 X1  X2  X3  X4   X5
1     195 86 186 342 744 1096
2     196 22  84 189 185  538
```

Comment: This is just what I meant by "more elegant". Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

There might be a more elegant base R solution, but this works.

```
# Construct a nicely named vector with which to split your data.frame
breaks <- seq(1950, 2000, by=10)
names <- c("50's", "60's", "70's", "80's", "90's")
decade <- cut(as.numeric(row.names(df)), 
              seq(1950, 2000, by=10), labels=names, right=FALSE)

# by() splits df apart, operating on each of its pieces.
# do.call(rbind, ...) sutures the results back together.
do.call(rbind, by(df, decade, colSums))
#      X1  X2  X3  X4   X5
# 50's 86 186 342 744 1096
# 60's 22  84 189 185  538
```

Answer (score 2):

`by` is an option:

```
by(x,10*(as.numeric(rownames(x))%/%10),colSums)
INDICES: 1950
   1    2    3    4    5 
  86  186  342  744 1096 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
INDICES: 1960
  1   2   3   4   5 
 22  84 189 185 538
```