# Calculate cumulative sum per group in R data.frame (with dplyr)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, cumulative-sum

I have this `data.frame`:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
         id date     precip
      <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 59630200 20171225  0    
 2 59630200 20171226  0    
 3 59630200 20171227  0.600
 4 59630200 20171228  0    
 5 59630200 20171229  0    
 6 59630200 20171230  0    
 7 59630200 20171231  0    
 8 59630200 20180101  0.600
 9 49920100 20171225  0    
10 49920100 20171226  0    
11 49920100 20171227  0.900
12 49920100 20171228  0    
13 49920100 20171229  0    
14 49920100 20171230  0    
15 49920100 20171231  0    
16 49920100 20180101  1.60 
17  4530300 20171225  0    
18  4530300 20171226  0.200
19  4530300 20171227  0    
20  4530300 20171228  0
```

And I would like to add another column (maybe called cumulated or whatever), where I have the cumulative sum for each `id`-group. There is an approach described here: [R colSums By Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084439/r-colsums-by-group), but I did not manage to make it work. Also I wanted to use `dplyr` if possible. I though about somehting like:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(accumulated = colSums(precip))
```

But this does not work. Maybe someone has an idea:)

Comment: it works by just using `cumsum` instead of `colSums`...

Answer (score 0):

### Libraries

```
library(dplyr)
```

### Data

```
df <-
  structure(list(id = c(59630200L, 59630200L, 59630200L, 59630200L, 
                        59630200L, 59630200L, 59630200L, 59630200L, 49920100L, 49920100L, 
                        49920100L, 49920100L, 49920100L, 49920100L, 49920100L, 49920100L, 
                        4530300L, 4530300L, 4530300L, 4530300L), date = c(20171225L, 
                                                                          20171226L, 20171227L, 20171228L, 20171229L, 20171230L, 20171231L, 
                                                                          20180101L, 20171225L, 20171226L, 20171227L, 20171228L, 20171229L, 
                                                                          20171230L, 20171231L, 20180101L, 20171225L, 20171226L, 20171227L, 
                                                                          20171228L), precip = c(0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.9, 
                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.6, 0, 0.2, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                      -20L))
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(accumulated = cumsum(precip))
```

### Result

```
# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
         id     date precip accumulated
      <int>    <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 59630200 20171225    0           0  
 2 59630200 20171226    0           0  
 3 59630200 20171227    0.6         0.6
 4 59630200 20171228    0           0.6
 5 59630200 20171229    0           0.6
 6 59630200 20171230    0           0.6
 7 59630200 20171231    0           0.6
 8 59630200 20180101    0.6         1.2
 9 49920100 20171225    0           0  
10 49920100 20171226    0           0  
11 49920100 20171227    0.9         0.9
12 49920100 20171228    0           0.9
13 49920100 20171229    0           0.9
14 49920100 20171230    0           0.9
15 49920100 20171231    0           0.9
16 49920100 20180101    1.6         2.5
17  4530300 20171225    0           0  
18  4530300 20171226    0.2         0.2
19  4530300 20171227    0           0.2
20  4530300 20171228    0           0.2
```